# Unwanted Boundaries In mesh Lab

Tags: 3d, point-clouds, meshlab

I wanted to create a stl file from point cloud. After Surface reconstruction usig poisson I could get stl file but its closed(extra surface). My actual point cloud is not closed, how to remove this extra surface on the top and bottom Attached are the screenshots.

http://s13.postimg.org/9mtr0jgxz/snapshot00.png

http://s13.postimg.org/tsx8zfclj/snapshot800.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meshlab offers tools to delete vertices and faces. Just pick the vertex / face selector from the toolbar (see screenshot) and then delete the faces using delete tool on the very right side.

[image]

Note that there is a known bug (for years actually) where the frame rate drops on some PCs that makes the selection of vertices impossible (http://sourceforge.net/p/meshlab/bugs/348/). Installing the latest beta solved the problem for some people.

If nothing helps you can also use other mesh manipulation tools like blender.